# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - javascript flask

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want validate a similar form and I have variable number of instance (ex. members-0-name after  members-1-name). I use jQuery Validate plugin but I have a problem:

```
<form method="POST" id="form_band_details" class="form_band_details" action="/user/band">

<div><label for="members-0-name">Nome</label><input class="login_field" id="members-0-name" name="members-0-name" type="text" value="" /></div>

<div><label for="members-0-surname">Cognome</label><input class="login_field" id="members-0-surname" name="members-0-surname" type="text" value="" /></div>

<div><label for="members-0-birthdate">Data di nascita</label><input class="login_field datetime" id="members-0-birthdate" name="members-0-birthdate" type="text" value="" /></div>
```

I use this javascript:

```
$(function() {
$("#form_band_details").validate({
    debug : true,
    rules : {
        members-1-name : {
            required : true
        }

    },
    messages : {
        members-1-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-2-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-3-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-4-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-5-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-6-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-7-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-8-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-9-name : {
            required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
        },
        members-10-name : {
            required : true
        },
        members-1-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-2-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-3-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-4-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-5-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-6-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-7-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-8-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-9-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-10-surname : {
            required : "inserisci il cognome del componente"
        },
        members-1-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-2-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-3-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-4-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-5-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-6-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-7-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-8-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-9-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        },
        members-10-birthdate: {
            required : "inserisci la data di nascita"
        }

    },
    submitHandler : function(form) {
        form.submit()
    }
});
});
```

The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`

I understand the problem is `-` but I can't change the name of the variable beacuse is generated by server, the server use flask framework

Comment: `members-1-name` is not a valid identifier. Use `"members-1-name"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names need to be in quotes if they contain characters that aren't allowed in identifiers, such as `-`.

```
messages : {
    "members-1-name" : {
        required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
    },
    "members-2-name" : {
        required : "inserisci il nome del componente"
    },
    ...
```